The dialog box is not showing
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:authentication_signup/components/my_button.dart';
import 'package:authentication_signup/components/my_textfield.dart';
import 'package:authentication_signup/components/square_tile.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  //text editing controllers
  final usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  //sign user in method
  void signUserIn() async {
    //loading circle
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },);

    try {
      // Try signing in
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: usernameController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );

      // Close the loading dialog only if the widget is still mounted
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // Close the loading dialog only if the widget is still mounted
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }

      // Handle error
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        // Show error to user
        wrongEmailMessage();
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        // Show error to user
        wrongPasswordMessage();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle any other exceptions and close the loading dialog if mounted
      if (mounted) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  // Wrong email message pop-up
  void wrongEmailMessage() {
    if (mounted) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Incorrect email'),
            content: Text('No user found with that email.'),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  // Wrong password message pop-up
  void wrongPasswordMessage() {
    if (mounted) {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Incorrect password'),
            content: Text('The password you entered is incorrect.'),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

Ensure the Widget is Mounted: If the widget has been unmounted during the async operation, attempting to show a dialog will fail. Always check if the widget is still mounted before calling Navigator.pop(context) or showing dialogs.
Async gaps: asynchronous operations (like signing in with Firebase) may cause issues with the BuildContext. Use the mounted property to check if the widget is still in the tree.
Flutter Build Context: Ensure that you're using the right BuildContext when calling Navigator or showDialog.
I tried these and updated the code but still the dialog box is not showing when i put a wrong email or password. its just not logging in and staying in the login page itself with no pop up dialog box for the user
